# Eclipse Android project SVN checkout: folder locked

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, subversive, locked

Trying to check out my Android project from an SVN repository, I got the following error:

0x0000000f: The folder 'E:\workspace\mc-01-02\project.properties' is locked by some external process. Please unlock the folder and try to check out the project again.

project.properties actually is a file, not a folder.

As a test, I created another project and added the "project.properties" file to svn:ignore. I got this:

0x0000000f: The folder '/media/D/workspace/andi/.fuse_hidden00002a6900000003' is locked by some external process. Please unlock the folder and try to check out the project again.

Again, ".fuse_hidden00002a6900000003" is a file, not a folder. In both cases, the files were created with content and perfectly readable.

As you might have noticed, I tried this from a Windows Eclipse and a Linux Eclipse. (I have my workspace on my Windows partition.) Both attempts failed. Yet, checking out to a workspace on the Linux partition succeeded.

I'm using Eclipse Galileo with the Subversive plugin.

This might be a problem with Android tools interfering?!?

Input, anyone?

Comment: Okay, so I checked out the project to my Linux workspace and imported it into my Windows workspace. I didn't know that Eclipse would copy the repository information! However, I had to manually copy and paste some files' contents... But for now, the workaround seems to work for me.

Comment: Meh, it didn't actually _copy_ the files to my Windows partition, so I still can't access them from within Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Select the project
Right click on the selected Project
Team -> Cleanup

Then try